# How to update a specific line in text file with XCODE

Tags: objective-c

I use Xcode5 to build an application and need to update a content of a specific line in text file.

Comment: Are you editing the file *in* XCode, or using XCode to develop code (in Objective C, or C++, or whatever) to do the editing for you?

Comment: i am using XCode to develop code in Objective C

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is: Read in the entire file as an NSString; modify the resulting NSString; write the file back out again. NSString has methods for doing all of that.